# PHP DOM parse data by traversing nodes

Tags: php, parsing, dom, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I'm using this code to fetch the data from a html table:

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue; 
    echo '<br>';
    }
```

The data in the html table is in this format:

```
<tr>
<td>DATA 1</td>
<td>DATA 2</td>
<td>DATA 3</td>
<td>DATA 4</td>
<td>DATA 5</td>
</tr>
```

My for loop displays the data in this format:

```
DATA 1DATA 2DATA 3DATA 4DATA 5
DATA 1DATA 2DATA 3DATA 4DATA 5
DATA 1DATA 2DATA 3DATA 4DATA 5
```

I have also tried using the code to look at `$dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $node)` which displays the text from each table cell on different lines

Is it possible to store each cell data in an array ?
I've tried using $data=array() on the page but arrays don't seem to work with DOMDocument?

Many thanks!

Comment: what is your desired output

Comment: I guess my desired output is to store the table of data in my own database.  As a first step I was trying to separate the table of data into individual cells ( <td> ) and storing these in different arrays.  I'm currently reading this SO page which also looks at parsing a html table.  Let me know if you have any ideas that could help, thanks!